# How do I change the code comment settings of vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, intershop

Our current tool Intershop outputs comments as

```
<!--- comment here --->
```

Instead of

```
<!-- comment here -->
```

Now if I edit these files in code it looks like

[image]

Where in vscode can I change something so that my `<!---comment--->` code will be recognized as begin and start comment tags?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What language do you use? HTML for example? How are you adding the comment? By pressing `Ctrl+/`?

Comment: for now its recognized as xml. Its a special comment tag especially for Intershop . This allows you to add comment in your code that do not get rendered in the output, isml is a combination of html and custom tags